# Syntax error while executing a python script to make a web application

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, pycharm

this is my first time using pycharm and flask library. i am fairly new to advanced programing and i was trying to create an executable link for my program but im getting a syntax error. when i run the same script in idle without the flask functions and without the `if __name__=="__main__":` line in python IDLE, it works just as expected.

```py
from flask import Flask
import os
import csv
import sqlite3
import tkinter.filedialog
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

k=Tk()
k.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
database=sqlite3.connect("C:\SQLiteStudio\data.db")
d=database.cursor()
task1="""CREATE TABLE z (
        date DATE ,
        time TIME ,
        value_1 DOUBLE PRECISION ,
        value_2 DOUBLE PRECISION ,
        final_value DOUBLE
    );"""
task2="""INSERT INTO z (date, time, value_1, value_2, final_value) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"""
#d.execute(task1)
out=pd.read_csv(k.filename, header=None)
print(len(out))
print(out.iloc[0])
row=1
if str(out.iloc[0,0])=='Date' and str(out.iloc[0,1])=='Time' and str(out.iloc[0,2])=='Lat' and str(out.iloc[0,3])=='Long' and str(out.iloc[0,4])=='Temp':
    while row< len(out):
        print(row)  
        d.execute(task2,out.iloc[row])
        database.commit()
        row+=1
else:
    print("The data is not in expected format.")
database.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
"C:\Users\Jay Paliwal\Desktop\Internship\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/Jay Paliwal/Desktop/Internship/task 1.py"
File "C:/Users/Jay Paliwal/Desktop/Internship/task 1.py", line 13
        k=Tk()
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the output I got. I was expecting a link to come which when one visited opens a dialogue box for the tkinter function used

Answer (score 0):

You can't just have a decorator on its own. A decorator needs to state a function.

Your code should be in a function anyway.

(Note though, it makes no sense to try to use tkinter in a Flask app. Why are you using Flask at all here?)